# How to force use SMTP servers in Alpine?

Tags: smtp, alpine-mail

Does anybody know how to force Alpine to use a particular SMTP server from the config list?

It seems to choose the first server in the SMTP list in config, but I want to be able to choose the SMTP server per message.

I tried using different SMTP servers in Roles, but that didn't work at all.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Could you please provide the settings in Roles that didn't work? We may be able fix it.